# How to use BTCRelay for my ICO to get funds in BTC?

Tags: solidity, ico, ethereumjs, btcrelay

I want my ICO get investment in BTC also ,When i browse over internet I came up with BTCRelay concept . I tried to read their docs but it make me confused .Anybody give me a simple way to use BTC relay for the distribution of the ERC20 based token.

Any help is appreciable!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, relaying was a bit too pricey for not many users, so you'd have to run the whole thing yourself (relay everything).  You can see the contract was sort of abandoned: https://etherscan.io/address/0x41f274c0023f83391de4e0733c609df5a124c3d4

But to explain how it works, you can have a BTC wallet and use BTCRelay to verify that people are sending BTC to it through a contract on the Ethereum network.  Then once they deposit the money, you could issue them a token.